# iOS Core data how to use NSPredicate to find parent objects based on one to many child properties?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, one-to-many

I have a Core Data model that goes as following:

A `ServiceProvider` Entity can have many `Service` Entities(one to many relationship). Each Service has a `type` attribute.

How can I use the `type` attribute of the `Service` entity to search for `ServiceProviders` that have services with that type?

Below is an example that I currently have that works for a single service relationship. **How can I modify the predicate below to work for multiple services?**

```
  NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSManagedObjectContext* context = [HealthDataManager sharedInstance].managedObjectContext;

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ServiceProvider" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];



    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.service.type == %i",type]];

    NSArray* results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

    if(results.count>0)
    {
        for(ServiceProvider* provider in results)
        {
            DLog(@"found provider: %@", [provider description ]);
        }
        return [results lastObject];
    }else{
        DLog(@"Creating provider" );
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To find objects that have *any* related service with the given type, use the predicate

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY services.type == %i",type];
```

(assuming that "services" is the name of the to-namy relationship).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use subqueries for that: `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SUBQUERY(service, $service, $service.type == %i).@count) > 0"];`.

For more informations about how subqueries and other predicate work you should checkout the [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html).

Comment: Note that `$service.type` should be `$a.type` to make this work.

Comment: Interesting, these subqueries look pretty powerful, I will have to remember how to do them.